JsonObject string name in arduino json
How can I put a string as object name?
for example...
 String nameObj = "test";
      JsonObject nameObj = Data.add<JsonObject>();

My compiler is Arduino and I use esp32 hardware.
To use json, I use the Arduino json library

You should use dictionary to specify a an array of JsonObjects with string as keys. Then you can use 'nameObj' variable to obtain the value from the dictionary. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/dictionary/

Thank you ,
Actually, I want to use the string because I want to change the name of the object dynamically, and I said to myself that I should make this change inside the string so that the name of the object will also change, do you know a way that I can change the name of the object dynamically?
`code   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  JsonObject Data_ + i = Data.add<JsonObject>();

  Data_0["SSID"] = WiFi.SSID(i);

}`


The question is more or less of "how to create an json object" in c/c++. Arduino users nowadays over depend on library that they forgot how to create an json object natively. For simple json object, you don't have to rely on ArduinoJson to create an json object, you can hand craft an serialised json object without any library.
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();

    const int arraySize= n * MAX_SSID_LEN;
    String output;
    output.reserve(arraySize);  // reserve enough space to avoid heap fragmentation

    output = "{\"SSID\":[";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      output = output + "\"" + WiFi.SSID(i) + "\"";
      (i < (n-1)) ? output += "," : output += "]";
    }
    output += "}";

    Serial.println(output);

Update
As per the comment below from @ryn, I don't really agreed to the comment, which sounds like "cargo cult" to me. Whether to use the ArduinoJson or not should be based on the context and actual application. Buf If one insists of using ArduinoJson is the best practice, by all means, use it, you can do so with the following code (based on ArduinoJson 6.0 API).
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();

    const int arraySize= n * MAX_SSID_LEN;
    String output;
    output.reserve(arraySize);  // reserve enough space to avoid heap fragmentation

    // using ArduinoJson v6.0 API
    StaticJsonDocument<512> doc; // make sure the magic number 512 is greater than the n*MAX_SSID_LEN
    
    JsonArray jarray = doc.createNestedArray("SSID");
    
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      jarray.add(WiFi.SSID(i));
    } 
    serializeJson(doc, output);

    Serial.println(output);


This is bad practice, as your codebase grows and you don't expect a constant response from your server, trying to adapt this code with changes will be a big mess. theres a reason why arduinojson is prefered, and its listed on their websites. its simply better practice.

Intro
There is a lack of specification in what your trying to do, but by other comments if your trying to have json responses, you should use the arduino json library.
Getting started
Again due to the lack of code you provided the safest way is to utilize their own assistant on their website here. It will provide the exact code and you can just change or make it adapt to your current codebase.
Issues
If you have issues with this library the safest bet is to ask the core developers , although please include a better description and elaborate further
